# Akkadian Prophecies and Daniel

Tags: hebrew-bible, daniel, authorship, babylon

There are currently five Babylonian cuneiform “ex eventu” texts known as the Akkadian Prophecies. They are dated as old as 1st millennium BC (I think) but the youngest one dates to the early 3rd century BC known as the Dynastic Prophecy. In terms of literacy style, form and phrasing they have numerously been observed as having similarities to that of Daniel 11.

One could then easily explain the similarities as a result of the author of Daniel being in the midst of such Babylonian literature because the author lived in Babylon during the time that the literature was widely available. Therefore this serves as evidence of an early date (sixth century) for the book of Daniel.

However, there are scholars who hold to the late date (mid second century) in spite of the Akkadian Prophecies. One lecturer suggested that the author somehow got a hold of these prophecies, or others like it, in the form of a language which a second century Jew in Palestine could understand - observing that **“formidable cuneiform script would prevent any first hand acquaintance.”**

Is it reasonable to suggest such a thing? Why would anyone want to transcribe onto papyri the Akkadian Prophecies or others like it in a more common language? Why would the author even bother trying to match up the style of Daniel 11 to pagan prophecies? Were the cuneiform texts even available in the second century for someone to transcribe?

I know my questions are bias but I believe one has to have some level of bias and hope so as to know where to start in the discovery for the truth!

Comment: Too broad. Do you have a particular verse or verses in mind that tie to the Akkadian prophesies?  Or can you tailor this to address just the scriptures?

Comment: The details in the parallels between Daniel and the Akkadian Prophecies aren’t relevant to the actual questions I’m asking

Comment: then how is hermenuetics applicable to this question?  If a scripture is not the basis for your question, is this the right site for it?

Comment: I put in a very similar question into Christianity stack exchange and it was moved to here. I’ve posted and got answers for many questions relating to apologetics (which this post relates to) on Hermeneutics. If I posted it anywhere else such as history I may get a secular answer from someone who holds to a second century date to Daniel. I’m looking for an answer from some who holds the traditional view.

Answer (score -1):

No, their argument against the authorship of Daniel based upon formidable cuneiform script is bogus.

The Akkadian prophesies that have been gathered from the archeological sites in old Babylon and Assur are compiled and printed from bits and pieces verified by archeologists, and then reviewed by people in academia with initials behind their names.  Does that give them such a cloak of authority that their opinions can rival or stand against the word of God?

This is a point that comes up frequently by those who bring into question the man or men who are the "authors" of the books of both the old and new testaments as though those men were solely responsible for the scriptures.  It is an effort to cast doubt upon God's word and to bring into question His authority over all.

The ultimate author of the scriptures is the Holy Spirit.

> *"20 this first knowing, that no prophecy of the Writing doth come of private exposition, 21 for not by will of man did ever prophecy come, but by the Holy Spirit borne on holy men of God spake."*  (2 Pet. 1:20-21, YLT)

The Holy Spirit moved the writers of the books to speak and write the words.  They were in essence His secretaries.  Was the style of the language similar to the existing language of their culture and their day?  That would be obviously necessary for the people to understand what was being said.  But that does not mean that the source of the books is from the worldly culture of that day.

Those who rebel against God's word and God's authority have used this type of argument repeatedly to cast doubt upon the authenticity of Daniel and other books because they cannot believe that the prophesies were so accurate.  We are told that we can know if a prophet was speaking the truth by the name of God if the event came to pass (Deu. 18:20-22).

So the unbelievers have to justify the events that came to pass as "ex eventu" in order to rationalize their unbelief.  Those with critical analytical skills are able to examine evidences to determine if there are external and internal proofs of God's word, and can know that His word is true (Psa. 119:160; John 17:17)  The more I have researched and tested this the more certain I am.

Those who have examined the claims of the unbelievers that Daniel was written in the 3rd or 2nd centuries BC after the fact, or "ex eventu" find that the claims do not have merit.

Excerpt from "Some Literary Affinities in the Book of Daniel" by Joyce G. Baldwin 1978:

> "The future is the immediate future of the reigning monarch and the ideal is stability in family and state. There is nothing resembling biblical eschatology. Indeed Professor Grayson emphasizes that there is no evidence in Babylonian thought of any eschatology. 'In fact there was no word for "history" in their language'. 'The ideal was a long and pious reign.'/24/

> This lack of any sense of a goal to history marks a major difference between these Babylonian texts and their biblical counterparts. Despite some superficial likenesses it is a difference which would inevitably affect the whole concept of prophecy. 'An Akkadian prophecy', writes A. K. Grayson, 'is a prose composition consisting in the main of a number of "predictions" of past events. It then concludes either with a "prediction" of phenomena in the writer's own day or with a genuine attempt to forecast future events. The author, in other words, uses
> vaticinia ex eventu to establish his credibility and then proceeds to his real purpose, which might be to justify a current idea or institution or, . . . to
> forecast future doom for a hated enemy.'/25/ That biblical prophecy is of an altogether different nature hardly needs to be argued. The literary prophets of
> the Bible were validated by their conviction that the Creator God, in covenant with his people, expected loyalty to the terms of that covenant and would himself
> remain, true to his promise."  Source: Tyndale Bulletin 30, p. 85  [TyndaleHouse](https://legacy.tyndalehouse.com/tynbul/Library/TynBull_1979_30_04_Baldwin_LiteraryDaniel.pdf)

Their argument against Daniel being a true prophesy of God is grasping at straws.

Comment: I’m afraid this doesn’t answer any of my questions in the post

Comment: You asked if it was reasonable, and I think I answered that it was not.  You asked why they would bother, & I thought it was clear that they mean to throw doubt upon God as the source of the prophesy.

Comment: The answer is focused on the theory that Daniel was written in mid second century BC (the Maccabean Hypothesis). I wanted answers that revolves around the claim that the supposed second century author of Daniel 11 could get become familiar of the Akkadian Texts via translated versions of them. I believe my post is clear on that.

Comment: Your are bringing a bias into your desired answer.  Daniel was not written in the 2nd cent. BC, therefor your position is not tenable.

Comment: Read source doc linked in the answer all the way through, and see also this one at ApologeticsPress.org - https://apologeticspress.org/the-date-of-daniel-does-it-matter-5359/

Comment: My questions are based on bias as I mention but not towards the second century date as you’ve said but towards the sixth century date. The link you’ve sent has nothing to do with the Akkadian Prophecies and their relation to Daniel.